# show specific div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code what it does that it shows some circles on click, but when i click on one of them all of the circles appear, i don't want that, what i want is with each click only the circles under the word "click" to appear not all of them, how can i do that? here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
        $('.circle').toggle()
    });
});
```

```css
.circle{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  transform: scale(0);
}


  .circle{
    animation: popin .25s forwards;
    }
    
    .circle:nth-of-type(1){
   
      top: 22px;
      left: 80px;
      }
    .circle:nth-of-type(2){
      top: 22px;
      left: 48px;
      }
    .circle:nth-of-type(3){
      top: 22px;
      left: 16px;
      }

@keyframes popin {
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-wS9gmOZBqsqWxgIVgA8Y9WcQOa7PgSIX+rPA0VL2rbQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="circles">
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <div class="clickme">click</div>
   </li>
 </ul>
 
 <ul>
  <li class="circles">
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <div class="clickme">click</div>
   </li>
 </ul>
 
 <ul>
  <li class="circles">
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <div class="clickme">click</div>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.circle` will target all `.circle`s. To target the `.circle`s before the `.clickme` element you click on, you can use `$.siblings()` since they're adjacent to `.clickme`

```js
$(function() {
    $clickme = $('.clickme');
    $(document).on('click','.clickme',function(e) {
      $(this).closest('ul').siblings('ul').find('.circle').hide();
      $(this).siblings('.circle').toggle();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }).on('click',function() {
      $('.circle').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.circles { position: relative; }
.circle{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  transform: scale(0);
}


  .circle{
    animation: popin .25s forwards;
    }
    
    .circle:nth-of-type(1){
   
      top: 22px;
      left: 80px;
      }
    .circle:nth-of-type(2){
      top: 22px;
      left: 48px;
      }
    .circle:nth-of-type(3){
      top: 22px;
      left: 16px;
      }

@keyframes popin {
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-wS9gmOZBqsqWxgIVgA8Y9WcQOa7PgSIX+rPA0VL2rbQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<ul>
  <li class="circles">
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <div class="clickme">click</div>
   </li>
 </ul>
 
 <ul>
  <li class="circles">
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <div class="clickme">click</div>
   </li>
 </ul>
 
 <ul>
  <li class="circles">
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <button class="circle"></button>
  <div class="clickme">click</div>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: @jessica does this solution not work for you? If not, please explain why.

Comment: It did but i have changed my code i can't use the next anymore, check my html code you'll know why

Comment: @jessica why did you change your code? Please avoid doing that if possible, because any answers folks give will then be invalid.

Comment: @jessica ok, it will be a few minutes, working on something different right now.

Comment: can you help me out in something? i want when the user clicks out the div and the circles are opened to close how can i do it?

Comment: @jessica there are a few ways you can do it. updated my answer with one way.

Comment: thank you so much but one more thing, when i click on a div and open it then i click on the second div, the first one doesn't close, how can i fix that?